# wordpress the_post method in custom category page not showing top viewed post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Most viewed posts(in Customer Category), in home page I have added this widget and it works perfect, in detail page also it works perfect but in category page the same widget behaves strangely

```
$r = new WP_Query( array( 'tax_query' => 
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'custcategory', 
                            'field' => 'term_id', 
                            'terms' => array(10)), 
                        ),
                        'category__in'=>array(10),
                        'post_type'=> $post_type , 
                        'posts_per_page' => $number, 
                        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                        'order' => 'DESC'  ) ); 

if ($r->have_posts()) :
    // Enters this block in home page and detail page
    while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post();
else:
    // Enters this block in category page
```

Anyone know why this strange behavior is?

Comment: Where is `the_post()` method?

Comment: @rnevius updated plz check

Comment: What is that strange behavior exactly?

Comment: @ThemesCreator in the category page alone most viewed posts differs but in home page and detail page it remains same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some filter that is affecting categories page, add this to your query args:

```
'suppress_filters' => true
```

You can also try adding wp_reset_query() after your main query, but this should not be necessary because you are declaring a new WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that your query args are wrong. You have set a relation, but you only have one taxonomy array. Also you don't need the `'category__in'=>array(10)` argument, it is only for the default taxonomy "category" and you want only posts from your custom taxonomy "custcategory", isn't it?

Your query should be:

```
$r = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custcategory', 
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => array(10)
        ), 
    ),
    'post_type'=> $post_type , 
    'posts_per_page' => $number, 
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC' 
));
```